# Could Xcode be crashing my SSD?

Tags: xcode, ssd

So here's an adventure.

Twice my system has stopped working completely (gets stuck on endless loop booting, requires OS reinstall even to be able to get at a backup.  Once, in spring 2015 on Yosemite. The second time, in spring 2016 on El Capitan.

The only common factor between those two cases was this: it was immediately after downloading Xcode the first time around, and immediately after updating it, the second (in both cases from the App Store).

The only theory I have here is that the sheer size of the download or whatever the App Store is doing to install is somehow, I dunno, overwriting some kind of boot record, or corrupting sectors (do SSDs even have sectors these days?) or some other madness.

And so here I am, months later, still and endlessly clicking "remind me later" because I'm terrified to try the Xcode update again (I don't even remember what I did to get it to actually install the first time) and have another week of sacrificing goats to Satan to get the recovery partition to let me yet again reinstall the os and restore my damn hard drive.

Do the wiser heads around here think I'm just deluded?  Am I concocting a fantasy theory based on my total lack of knowledge of how SSDs and booting and such work?  My google-fu reveals no tales of anyone else having this particular issue, but the coincidence seems too much to ignore.

If it matters, I have a late 2013 13in rMBP, with no shortage of anything (2.8ghz i7, 16gb ram, a half-tb factory SSD with a solid hundred gb free). Any ideas would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks!

Comment: I really don't think OS X will overwrite system files with Xcode. Did you MacBook come with that SSD, or did you install it yourself?

Comment: It's the factory SSD.

Comment: Does Xcode work?

Comment: Ish?  As much as it ever does.  I don't really use it a lot.